# Spring Context Hierarchy with Web Application Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm dealing with a Spring MVC web app that's bootstrapped using a `DispatcherServlet`. It creates a `XmlWebApplicationContext` which manages the whole application:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:springmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now there are some modules that should be loaded at runtime using a `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator`. Therefore every module has its own `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext`. So that a module could reference beans from the `XmlWebApplicationContext`, it should be attached to the `XmlWebApplicationContext` to form a Context Hierarchy  wherein the `XmlWebApplicationContext` should play the role of the parent and the `ClasspathXmlApplicationContext` of the module the role of the child context. Unfortunately I'm unable to connect them using

```
<beans>
    <bean id="moduleContext"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
            ...
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="parentContext" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

because I've found no way so far to give the `WebApplicationContext` the name `parentContext`. Have I overlooked something or is there a better/easier way to achieve the same in a different fashion?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using annotations, you can do this:

```
@Inject
private XmlWebApplicationContext context;

@Inject
private List<ClassPathXmlApplicationContext> childs;

@PostConstruct
public void refreshContext() {
    for(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext : childs) {
        appContext.setParent(context);
    }
    context.refresh();
}
```

You can do it without annotations too, by using the interfaces InitializingBean and ApplicationContextAware.

**Edited:** `childs` is autowired by type, so Spring will inject all the bean that are being an instance of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

Comment: Where do I get `childs` from if I don't know them in advance?

Comment: I tried the code you propose. It works, but doesn't propagate to the `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator`. But it leads in the right direction: The way to go is not to use a `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator` but to manually load the child contexts (using a `GenericApplicationContext`) and attach them to the parent context in a `InitializingBean`.